# Extra blank page before References when the last page is full - APA6 A4 template, Xetex

Tags: biblatex, xetex, apa-style, apa6

I badly need your expert help, tried to find solutions to no avail.

In a simple document when the last page is full, LaTeX will render a blank page before inserting the references. If the last page is not full, there is no blank page.

I think I haven't used anything special so I have no idea what this is and how to fix it.
Help please!

Full sample on Overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/read/gxwqhdvwkfnv

Command used for PDF generation: latexmk -pdf -xelatex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,floatsintext,biblatex-apa,oneside]{apa6}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\addbibresource{a.bib}

\title{Title}
\shorttitle{shortTitle}
\author{Me}
\affiliation{Piglet}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\parencite{vanmerrienboerTransferParadoxEffects1997} word word word 
word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
... until the page fills up ...
word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The maintainer of `apa6.cls` seems to have agreed this behaviour was a bug and fixed it in v2.33 dated 2018/09/01 (see https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live-commits/2018-September/007258.html)
>
> The analysis below is left for historic interest

In `man` mode `apa6.cls` defines

```
\defbibheading{bibliography}{\section*{\newpage\normalfont\refname}}%
```

so it automatically adds a clear page before the bibliography. You can turn that off with

```
\AtEndPreamble{%
  \defbibheading{bibliography}{\section*{\normalfont\refname}}%
}
```

or maybe (if you want the bibliography to start on a page of its own, but not leave an empty page)

```
\AtEndPreamble{%
  \defbibheading{bibliography}{\clearpage\section*{\normalfont\refname}}%
}
```

This has to happen in the `\AtEndPreamble` hook because that is where `apa6` makes its bibliography settings.

You may want to double check your APA manual and contact the developer of the [`apa6`](https://ctan.org/pkg/apa6) class (contact information can be found in the manual http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/apa6/apa6.pdf) if the current behaviour does not conform to APA style.

Comment: You are a lifesaver, thanks @moewe! One thing I don't understand is why it only adds a new page if the last line is not empty. In the example above if you delete a few "word"s so the last line becomes empty, the empty page will be removed too. I'll check with the author of APA6 too - I believe the blank page is not APA6 compliant.

Comment: @Adam That weird behaviour has to do with the placement of `\newpage` in the original definition. It is placed *within* the argument of `\section*`. So the section heading is literally `\newpage References`. The behaviour of that combination is slightly different from `\newpage\section*{\refname}` where we would get a new page and then the section heading `References`. In particular `\section*{\newpage\normalfont\refname}` might be moved to the next page if there is not enough space on the last page of text. This new page would then be met with `\newpage` and so you get an empty page. ...

Comment: ... If on the other hand there is enough space on the last page of text for a heading (as calculated by LaTeX), then `\newpage` is executed on the last page of text leaving us only with the bibliography on a new page and no empty page. This unclear behaviour makes me think that no matter what the APA manual says, `\section*{\newpage\normalfont\refname}` is questionable behaviour either way.

Comment: It makes sense @moewe. Do you think the best approach is to use \clearpage\section*{\normalfont\refname}, as per your last example? I could get the author (Brian) to incorporate this change.

Comment: @Adam That depends on whether the references should start on a new page or not. If the references should be on a new page `\clearpage\section*{\refname}` is the sensible thing to do, if they don't start a new page I would just use `\section*{\refname}`. But the class developer will know (i) what exactly is required and (ii) the best way to fix this. So if I were you I would not worry too much about proposing the perfect solution, the by far more important thing is that you reported this issue in the first place.